# Bind to default property value of another control style definition in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `CustomControl` and want to have the default value of `TextBox` default style definition. I don't know if it that is even possible.

This is what I have tried so far without success. But here you can see what I have in mind.

My default implementation to change the default style of the `TextBox` (in for example app.xaml to apply it global)

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
</Style>
```

---

Here I want to get the value of '2'.

```
<Style TargetType="controls:CustomControl">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static TextBox.BorderThicknessProperty}}"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value of the `BorderThickness` property of a `TextBox` is defined in the default style of the `TextBox` which is eventually applied to an instance of a `TextBox` at runtime.

So you cannot do something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:CustomControl">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static TextBox.BorderThicknessProperty}}"/>
</Style>
```

...unless you bind to an actual instance of a `TextBox` that uses the default style.

You could look at the default template of the `TextBox` and simply copy its default `BorderThickness` property value of `1` though:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:CustomControl">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
</Style>
```

Obviously you can also bind to a property of a class from more than one `Style`, e.g.:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:CustomControl">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding Thickness, Source={StaticResource settings}}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: That is not what I want to have. If I change the default Style of `TextBox`, I don't want to have a look at all my `CustomControls` which uses the same default `BorderThickness`.

Comment: How else are you going to do it? There is no implicit relationship between a CustomControl and TextBox. And like I said, the default value of the BorderThickness only exists in the default style.

Comment: By the way, you can't change the default style. If you define an implicit Style, you might as well set its BorderThickness property to the same value that you use in your CustomControl. Just define a property somwhere and bind to this one.

Comment: I have made som edits on my question, where you can see what I mean with "change the default style". It's more extend/modify the default style.

Comment: I had overlooked that! Ok so I think need to define some static properties in my ResourceDictionaries. Thanks anyway

Comment: I will define them like my other colors to get them via `Theme` markupExtensions. `<system:Int32 x:Key="Control_BorderThickness">1</system:Int32>`. Usage will be sth. like `<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ht:Theme Key=Control_BorderThickness}"/>`

Comment: You have already answered my question with "..So you cannot do something like this:" and your comment "
By the way, you can't change the default style. If you define an implicit Style, you might as well set its BorderThickness property to the same value that you use in your CustomControl. Just define a property somwhere and bind to this one", I have just told you that I wont use an extra class, I will use my internal theme markup extension.

Comment: Can be closed or deleted